# How to rollback outer transaction by throwing an error in trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are two tables. The second one has a trigger with an 'instead of' clause, where a check is performed. If the check fails, an exception is thrown. However, my issue is that despite the exception being thrown, the record still remains in the first table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger
ON MyTable2
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE Name = 'Name2') //-- Just a simple example. I need a complex check. 
   BEGIN
      THROW;
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO MyTable2 (Id, Name) (SELECT * FROM inserted)
   END
END
```

---

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
   INSERT INTO MyTable1(Id, Name) VALUES (1, 'Name1')
   INSERT INTO MyTable2(Id, Name) VALUES (1, 'Name2')
   COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

My code is just an example to express my thoughts. So, my question is whether it's possible to rollback the whole (outer) transaction throwing an exception inside a trigger?

Comment: Your trigger isn't complete. You can't re`THROW` unless it's inside a `TRY...CATCH`; as you aren't there's no error *to* `THROW`. You need to define the error in your `IF`.

Comment: Yes, but something is fishy here. See the fiddle, it raises the error inside the trigger: https://dbfiddle.uk/kjFPtzrB  But it seems to want to continue the execution. I guess this is because by default the incorrect THROW error isn't batch aborting. SET XACT_ABORT doesn't seem to help either, it doesn't go to the CATCH

Comment: It's not "fishy" the trigger doesn't exist due to the syntax error, @siggemannen . [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8E_YTzaN) As such the trigger not doing anything is expected, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Ohhhh. I didn't see that! Thanks @ThomA

Comment: Triggers and errors are no replacement for UNIQUE or CHECK constraints. What is the complex check that can't be done otherwise?

Comment: Why use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger anyway? Why not an `AFTER` trigger? And yeah you could have just use a check constraint `CHECK (Name <> 'Name2')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you've ignored the error when you created your trigger:

> To rethrow an error, a THROW statement must be used inside a CATCH block. Insert the THROW statement inside a CATCH block, or add error parameters to the THROW statement.

This error means your trigger **was not created**. As a result expecting that trigger to do something is wrong; the trigger *does not exist*.

You need to fix the syntax error in your trigger and `THROW` an actual error, not try and re`THROW` an error that can't exist.

Something like this for your DDL would be appropriate:

```sql
USE Sandbox;
Go

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1 (ID int IDENTITY,
                         SomeString varchar(10) NOT NULL);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2 (ID int IDENTITY,
                         AnotherString varchar(10) NOT NULL);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER SomeTrigger ON dbo.Table2
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS--Is instead of really what you want?
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE AnotherString = 'abc')
        THROW 79862, N'Describe your error reason here.', 16;
    INSERT INTO dbo.Table2 (AnotherString)
    SELECT AnotherString
    FROM inserted;
END;
GO
```

Now we can use `XACT_ABORT` (no need for a `TRY...CATCH`) and try to `INSERT` values that are "bad":

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 (SomeString)
    VALUES('abc');
    INSERT INTO dbo.Table2 (AnotherString)
    VALUES('abc');
COMMIT;
GO
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 (SomeString)
    VALUES('def');
    INSERT INTO dbo.Table2 (AnotherString)
    VALUES('def');
COMMIT;
GO

SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 (SomeString)
    VALUES('xyz'),('123');
    INSERT INTO dbo.Table2 (AnotherString)
    VALUES('xyz'),('abc');
COMMIT;
GO
```

And if you `SELECT` from the tables, you'll see that only the values `'def'` are in both tables.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FlhS03mV)